# JavaScript 'smooth scroll' will not scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery

**Question background:**

I'm developing a single page site using Twitter Bootstrap 3 within an ASP.NET MVC project.

**The problem:**

Im currently attempting to implement 'smooth scrolling' that should scroll to to the relevant div with clicked from the navbar drop down. At the moment when a section is clicked from the navbar drop down it 'jumps' to the div rather than scroll.

**The code:**

This following is my '_Layout.cshtml' markup with provides the navbar and footer. The JavaScript for the scroll is shown between the script tags:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>@ViewBag.Title - My ASP.NET Application</title>
@Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
    <script>
        $('#nav .navbar-nav li>a').click(function () {
            var link = $(this).attr('href');
            var offSet = 30;
            var targetOffset = $(link).offset().top - offSet;
            $('html,body').animate({ scrollTop: targetOffset }, 7000);
        });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">

    <nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation" id="nav">
        <div class="container">
            <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="/"><img src="images/logo.png" alt="yourLogo"></a>
            </div>

            <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li class="active"><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                            <li><a href="#myCarousel">Projects</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#Welcome">Welcome</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#features">Thing</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#About">About Me</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#Location">Location</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#Contact">Contact Me</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
        </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
    </nav>
</div>

<div class="container body-content">
    @RenderBody()
</div>

<footer>
    <!-- This HTML is outside the other container above i.e its separate. You need a container as this allows you to use bootstrap classes -->
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-2">
                <h6>Copyright &copy; 2014</h6>
            </div>

            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <h6>About Us</h6>
                <p>Chia dreamcatcher artisan vinyl Intelligentsia Banksy. Art party whatever cred wolf hella distillery Portland wayfarers Kickstarter, kale chips pug artisan +1 crucifix.</p>
            </div>

            <div class="col-sm-2">
                <h6>Navigation</h6>
                <ul class="unstyled">
                    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Links</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>

            <div class="col-sm-2">
                <h6>Follow Us</h6>
                <ul class="unstyled">
                    <li><a href="#">Twitter</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Facebook</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Google Plus</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div><!-- end col-sm-2 -->

            <div class="col-sm-2">
                <h6>Coded with<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-heart"> by Me</span></h6>


            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</footer>
</body>


@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
@RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
```

**Screenshots:**

The following screenshots shown that when the navbar option are clicked the page go to the correct div, but it ***will not*** scroll. Any help resolving this would be great.

[image]

Comment: You need to block the default behavior of the anchor, otherwise the browser will get the `#whatever` hash and jump the page before your event handler runs.

Answer (score 1):

After a bit more research and using this great example:http://alijafarian.com/responsive-page-scrolling-with-jquery-and-bootstrap/ I managed to produce the solution below which works perfectly.

```
 <script>

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#nav .navbar-nav li>a').on('click', function(event){
            event.preventDefault();
            var sectionID = $(this).attr("href");
            scrollToID(sectionID, 750);
        });

        function scrollToID(id, speed)
        {
            var offSet = 70;
            var targetOffset = $(id).offset().top - offSet;
            $('html,body').animate({scrollTop:targetOffset}, speed);
        }
        });
 </script>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try adding "px" to scrolltop :

```
$('#nav .navbar-nav li>a').click(function () {
        var link = $(this).attr('href');
        var offSet = 30;
        var targetOffset = $(link).offset().top - offSet;
        $('html,body').animate({ scrollTop: targetOffset + "px" }, 7000);
    });
```

or this :

```
$('#nav .navbar-nav li>a').click(function () {
        var link = $(this).attr('href');
        var offSet = 30;
        var targetOffset = $(link).offset().top - offSet;
        $('html,body').animate({ scrollTop: targetOffset }, 'slow');
    });
```

i think you need to execute it after the page is loaded :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#nav .navbar-nav li>a').click(function () {
        var link = $(this).attr('href');
        var offSet = 30;
        var targetOffset = $(link).offset().top - offSet;
        $('html,body').animate({ scrollTop: targetOffset }, 'slow');
    });
});
```

Answer (score -1):

```
    <script>
$(function() {
  $('a[href*=#]:not([href=#])').click(function() {
    if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {

      var target = $(this.hash);
      target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
      if (target.length) {
        $('html,body').animate({
          scrollTop: target.offset().top
        }, 1000);
        return false;
      }
    }
  });
});
</script>
```

Taken from: [http://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/smooth-scrolling/]

Comment: Yes, when the link is clicked instead of jumping it uses animate and a speed of 1000.

Comment: But that part isn't any different from what OP posted (other than the speed, which is not the issue.)

Comment: For OP, this snippet will help you do what you want to do, but it's a bad answer for not providing an explanation.